# How does cyclopentadienyl anion act as reducing agent?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox, coordination-compounds, organometallic-compounds

I am a second year university student, so I'm afraid my chemistry isn't great. I am looking for an explanation of how the $\ce{Cp-}$ anion acts as a reducing agent.

To contextualise - in a simple synthesis of ferrocene, a hydrated salt of $\ce{FeCl3}$ (the hexahydrate) was mistakenly added to a dry solution of LiCp in THF, which had been prepared by reacting n-BuLi and cyclopentadiene under nitrogen. Clearly anhydrous $\ce{FeCl2}$ was what was supposed to be added.

So far I know that a re-protonation of $\ce{Cp-}$ would occur upon addition of a hydrate to regenerate CpH and thus ruin the reaction.

However, the reaction was allowed to continue and some ferrocene was collected by vacuum sublimation, and therefore I know that something present must have reduced the $\ce{Fe^3+}$ to $\ce{Fe^2+}$ in order for some ferrocene to form. I assume this was the $\ce{Cp-}$ anion as I know this is oxidised by the air. I would expect this to be oxidation under basic conditions because of the LiOH created in the re-protonation step.

I am looking for the half-equation for the oxidation of $\ce{Cp-}.$
What does cyclopentadienyl anion oxidise to? Why are the cyclopentadienyl salts air-sensitive?

Comment: Isn't it better to describe cyclopentadiene $\ce{<=> H+}$ + cyclopentadienyl anion as an simply an acid-base reaction (no change of electron count for cyclopentadiene/cyclopentadienyl anion). The anion stabilized (aromaticity), and -- contrasting to cyclopentadiene -- not so prone to dimerization. On the other side, the cyclopentadienyl cation would be a considerable uphill battle (because of its antiaromaticity).  And to be specific, ferrocene is an example of a well known, air stable compound, too (*formally* $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$ and two units of $\ce{C5H^-_5}$).

Comment: Huh? No, cyclopentadiene ($\ce{C5H6}$), dicyclopentadiene ($\ce{C10H12}$). There is a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrocene#Via_Grignard_reagent) about ferrocene *via* Grignard reaction as if the metal could dissociate (like famously for the anthracene/Mg/THF complex [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnesium_anthracene)). Here, this would lead to Li which could reduce Fe(III) to Fe(II). *But* (and thus hesitant to post this as an answer), the C-Li bonds are even more polarized than C-Mg; this sets the first reaction in question.

Comment: Cyclopentadienyl *salts* are **not** air-sensitive. Some *complexes* are, but it's more of a fault of the central atoms than the ligand afaik.

Comment: Could you give an explanation as to why something like TlCp is less air sensitive @Mithoron - as per a couple of sources I've found that say this is sometimes used. What is it about the metal cation

Comment: equally why was LiCp suggested for this lab and not NaCp or KCp - why is the lithium Cp used most often

Comment: @MatildaWillcox LiCp is commercially available (as a solution), though it isn't *bread and butter* in every ochem lab.  And in case it were not in stock, cyclopentadiene is easily deprotonated by commercially solutions of BuLi (which is a widely used chemical in many concentrations and solvents). Of course, one could cut sodium and use it as a base, too. But its reaction with water has more *potential* danger than nBuLi. I don't recall we had potassium metal in the lab class (for its oxides, and even more pronounced reactivity vs. water).

Comment: Matilda: If you are interested in a second opinion as to what could be occurring here, relating apparently to a growing body of recent research I am discussing elsewhere on the photo induced reactivity of aqueous FeCl3, you are invited to search the internet. Note: my suggestion photo path may explain the initiation process and may present clues as to forming organic radicals and products observed.

Comment: Search "ajkoer fecl3 photosensitive" for an extensive review of old and very recent science which may be at play here.

Comment: @AJKOER Like in the body of a question, or answer, it is possible to link *directly* to the doi of a publication. E.g., `[primer cyclovoltammetry](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jchemed.7b00361)` coalesces into [primer cyclovoltammetry](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jchemed.7b00361).

Comment: @Buttonwood:  Thanks for the tip.  I do admire your knowledge base and if continue to read my material and research in cross-disciplines, you actually may be filing patents before me on ideas that, frankly are somewhat obvious for someone with a cross-discipline perspective.  Or, perhaps not making big mistakes, as in the case of the billion dollar US navy expenditure on light Aluminum warships complete with a iron attached propulsion system now rapidly dissolving in polluted waters (just a bit of galvanic chemistry).

Comment: I'd like to remind everyone that the comment section should not be used for extended discussions. Please use [chat] vor this purpose.

Answer (score 10):

**Disclaimer**: None of this constitutes proof; it's just an informed guess. Any corrections with reputable sources are welcome.

---

The simplest proposal seems to be single-electron transfer (SET) from $\ce{Cp-}$ to $\ce{Fe^3+}$. This forms the neutral cyclopentadienyl *radical* as well as $\ce{Fe^2+}$. This $\ce{Fe^2+}$ then reacts with any remaining unreduced $\ce{Cp-}$ to form ferrocene $\ce{FeCp2}$.

All in all for a balanced equation, we would need three equivalents of $\ce{Cp-}$ per equivalent of $\ce{Fe^3+}$. One equivalent for the redox reaction / SET:

$$\ce{Fe^3+ + Cp- -> Fe^2+ + Cp^.}$$

and two equivalents to form ferrocene:

$$\ce{Fe^2+ + 2Cp- ->FeCp2}$$

The radicals probably go off and dimerise, which leads to dihydrofulvalene $\ce{Cp-Cp}$. (Basically, [fulvalene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fulvalene), but with the middle double bond changed to a single bond.)

There is some support for this hypothesis, namely the accidental synthesis of ferrocene from $\ce{FeCl3}$ and $\ce{CpMgBr}$ (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrocene#Via_Grignard_reagent)), which Buttonwood also mentioned in the comments. This follows almost the same scheme as outlined above. In the present case we have $\ce{CpLi}$ instead of $\ce{CpMgBr}$, and there are definitely differences between Grignards and organolithiums, but to a first approximation I'd expect similar behaviour.

Organolithiums are known to sometimes react as single-electron reducing agents, too (e.g. [lithium–halogen exchange sometimes involves SET](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jo00383a023)) so it's hardly implausible that $\ce{CpLi}$ might behave similarly.

Comment: Thank you for being so kind:) That's really interesting. It this how it would oxidise in air as well? I found this on Wikipedia - 'Lithium cyclopentadienide is a colourless solid, although samples often are pink owing to traces of oxidised impurities'

Comment: @MatildaWillcox This comment is be even more speculative than my actual post, but... potentially yes? I could see Cp- doing a SET to oxygen (forming superoxide anion). Only difference is that it might react again after that to form oxygenated products. I don't think the pink colour tells us much though. Could be anything.

Comment: Given the cited history published in the ACS (see my answer) of the light sensitivity of FeCl3, this answer is well deserving of the provided disclaimer.

Comment: I have 4 citations on the photo abilities ascribed to aqueous FeCl3. To deny its possible role here is a losing game. But please, attempt to prove me wrong by adding more air/light exposure to your FeCl3 mix.

Comment: Per this source: ["The comparison of photocatalytic activity of Fe-salts, TiO2 and TiO2/FeCl3 during the sulfanilamide degradation process"](https://www.infona.pl/resource/bwmeta1.element.elsevier-df6d4600-bb15-3044-88a6-359e7a47a1c1), to quote: "Experiments were carried out in the presence of homogeneous Fe-salts (FeCl3 , Fe(NO3)3 , Fe2(SO4)3 , FeSO4 ), heterogeneous compounds (TiO2 ) and a mixture of catalysts (TiO2 /FeCl3 ) under UV-A and solar irradiation. Based on the comparison of several factors...  economic and ecological aspects, **FeCl3 is proposed as the optimal catalyst**."

Comment: @AJKOER I don't doubt that there are iron-based photocatalysts. However I speculate the OP run the reaction in a glass reactor which would block much of light in the range of UV. Except for the cells to record an UV-vis spectrum, teaching labs I have seen so far have few (if any) quartz containers. (The blue LEDs for photoredox chemistry [McMillan group etc.] might be a different story.)